# How to extract elements of an array in object type in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have an object which contains an array of **any type (not a priory known type. So I cannot a simple cast in the code because I can determine the type just in the run-time!)**. How can I extract the content of array?
For example:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
object obj=array;
...
//Here I know that obj is an array (<b>of a priory unknown type and I cannot use type conversion in the code </b> 
//How can extract elements of obj and use them, e.g. write them on the screen?`
```

Comment: do you have a real world reason for asking this?

Comment: The type of object in not known. For example, consider that I want to check the content of an unknown object. I know how to extract its field. If the field is a simple one, I can use it simply. But how is it when it is an array?

Comment: @Akhir sounds like you need to query the type.  Call `.GetType()` on the object to get type information, which you can then compare to known types using `typeof`, see my answer below.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth:Yes, but the problem is that I don't know that the type is "int". It is like when Visual Studio shows you the content of an object without knowing priory its type. In fact first it determines the type and then, it shows the content.

Comment: @Akhir that is why you **test** the type before you try to use it.  You know what type it might be, so you test the types you are interested in.  If you want to be able to handle every possible type, then it might be helpful to know what problem that will solve.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth: Thanks Adam for your help. But in fact, I don't know anything about what the type might be. I am working with an object that I just know it is array of something and I want to extract each element into an object and use that object (for example use ToString method).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An array is an `IEnumerable<T>,` using Covariance an `IEnumerable<object>`. That means **any** array is an `IEnumerable<object>.`

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
object obj=array;
IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)obj;

foreach (object item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand when u used obj (u used array directly).

Comment: @Akhir That was a typo, fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

You can cast it.

```
var myTempArray = obj as IEnumerable;

foreach (object item in myTempArray)
   ...
```

Comment: I don't know what is the type when I develop the code. I can determine it in run-time and so, I cannot cast the type in code.

Comment: @akhir note that `as` will swallow invalid casts and return a null reference, so check `myTempArray` for null before using it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (Again)**

If you know that the object is an array and you don't know the type of the array you can just cast it as an `object[]`.  This will defiantly work if all you have to do is call `toString()`.

For example

```
(obj as object[])
```

Comment: I don't know what is the type when I develop the code. I can determine it in run-time and so, I cannot cast the type in code.

Comment: @Akhir I changed the answer to work if you know its an array but don't know the type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it back to int[] and then extract the elements. After all, the fact that you know that is an array of integer doesn't reflect the fact that you're stating that is an object.

Look at it from the point of view of the compiler. All he know is that you've defined an object variable that, at that point, happens to be an array of integer, but which could change later on to another thing.. after all is just an object.

The constraints checks are performed by the runtime when you do the cast, so, logically, the compiler won't let you just use it as an array but require you to first CAST it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4.0 you could do make unnesscessary use of the `dynamic` keyword,

```
dynamic object obj = array;
Console.Write(obj[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you assign the `array` as the *value* of `obj`, you have made a cast. You will have to retrieve an item by casting again:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
object obj = array;

var i = ((int[])obj)[0];
```

If you don't know the type of the array, you will have to use generics:

```
object obj;

void StoreArray<T>(T array)
{
    obj = array;
}

T GetValue<T>(int index)
{
    return (T)(obj as T[])[index];
}
```

Note: unntested sample.