# Accessing elements of an Array (of any element type) from an object

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable, enumerable

I use management to access devices properties and I wrote a code below to create an array of dictionaries. my application show properties in a `listview` control; so I need to convert all properties value to simple string

```cs
Dictionary<string,string>[] getInfo(string k) {
    // using `k` as management-key
    var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"select * from {k}");
    var devices = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    var mosc = mos.Get();    // mosc is a collection of all devices with same key
    foreach (var device in mosc) {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var p in device.Properties) {
                if (p.Value != null) {
                    if (p.IsArray) {
                        // I have problem in here
                        // my application must convert p.value to string
                        var collection = (IEnumerable<object>)p.Value
                        properties[p.Name] = string.Join(", ", collection.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
                    } else
                        properties[p.Name] = p.Value.ToString();
                } else properties[p.Name] = "";
            }
        devices.Add(properties);
        }
    return devices.ToArray();
}
```

`p.Value` type is `object` but sometimes it contain an array like `UInt[]` or `String[]`, I found  part of code from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107668/how-to-extract-elements-of-an-array-in-object-type-in-c) but it didn't help me and it say:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.UInt16[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.'

I tried code below too, but it say same thing:

```cs
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }; // <- I haven't access to `array` in my main problem
object obj=array;
// I only can use `obj`
// `obj` is similar to `p.Value` here
IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)obj;   // <- this line throws exception!
string output=string.join(", ",collection.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```

I also tried this codes:

```
var collection= p.Value as IEnumerable;
// ^ found this line from stackoverflow
// says: Using the generic type 'IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

var collection= p.Value as IEnumerable<object>
// `collection` will be null

var collection= (object[]) p.Value
// says: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' (or some something like String[]) to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second code:

```cs
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
object obj=array;
var obj_array=(Array)obj;
IEnumerable<object> collection = obj_array.Cast<object>();
string output=string.join(", ",collection.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```

so main code will be:

```cs
Dictionary<string,string>[] getInfo(string k) {
    // using `k` as management-key
    var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"select * from {k}");
    var devices = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    var mosc = mos.Get();    // mosc is a collection of all devices with same key
    foreach (var device in mosc) {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var p in device.Properties) {
                if (p.Value != null) {
                    if (p.IsArray) {
                        var array = (Array)p.Value;
                        var collection = array.Cast<object>();
                        properties[p.Name] = string.Join(", ", collection.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
                    } else
                        properties[p.Name] = p.Value.ToString();
                } else properties[p.Name] = "";
            }
        devices.Add(properties);
        }
    return devices.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T` so this would be allowed:

```
IEnumerable<Giraffes> giraffes = ....
var animals = (IEnumerable<Animal>)giraffes;
```

So then, why does this not work as well?

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var objects = (IEnumerable<object>)array; //will not compile
```

`int` extends `object`, right?

Well, the reason is that type variance in C# is only allowed between *reference types*; the rule is that variance must preverse identity, and there is no way to cast a value type preserving identity in C#; only reference types can and those types of conversion are called *reference conversions*:

```
var animal = (Animal)giraffe;
var o = (object)"Hello";
IFish fish = cod;
//etc.
```

The bits that make up the object *dont change*, only the type of the refernece changes, hence the name of the conversion. Note that in the very first example, `animals` and `giraffes` are the same object, `object.ReferenceEquals(animals, giraffes)` will return `true`; we've only changed the type of the variable referencing it.

In your case, to obtain an `IEnumerable<object>` from an `IEnumerable<someValueType>`, you'll have to enumerate and box each item *creating a new enumerable* of the desired type. In order to do so, you can use the extension method `Enumerable.Cast<T>()`:

```
IEnumerable<object> objects = array.Cast<object>();
```

Or do the projection yourself:

```
IEnumerable<object> objects = array.Select(i => (object)i);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but second code is not my main question. My main problem is first code and there I haven't access to `array` I can only use `p.Value` in `object` type