# How to get values from the array, that put into the object?

Tags: c#, .net, types, reflection

I am making json parser so I need the universal method, thats why I can not `int[] arr = obj as int[];`

```
 int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
 object obj = array;
//I need to get value from the 'obj'
```

I tried to use reflection, but my knowledge is not enough to solve the problem.
Also I tried to use solutions from here [How to extract elements of an array in object type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107668/how-to-extract-elements-of-an-array-in-object-type-in-c) but it did not help me.

UPD

I am getting random object, and I must convert it into json format ecma-404. But I got problems with converting arrays, because I can not get values.

```
   private static string ReadObject(object obj) {
            string json = "{";
            TypedReference reference = __makeref(obj);
            foreach(var fromField in obj.GetType().GetFields()) {
                var toField = obj.GetType().GetField(
                    fromField.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                object value = fromField.GetValueDirect(reference);
                if(value == null)  json += toField.Name + ':' + "null" + ',';
                else json += toField.Name + ':' + WriteValue(value, value.GetType()) + ',';

            }
            json = json.Remove(json.Length - 1);
            json += '}';
            return json;
        }


 public static string SerializeArray(object obj) {
            string json = "[";
//here must be code
            return json;
        }
```

Comment: How did you use the solutions from the link? Please show some attempts at using the solutions from the link, and explain how they did not work.

Comment: Tried converting it back to array by doing `int[] arr = obj as int[];`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract elements of an array in object type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107668/how-to-extract-elements-of-an-array-in-object-type-in-c)

Comment: @MartinBaulig OP mentions that one _in the question_ as not answering his question.

Comment: `object obj = array;` - why do you do this in the first place?

Comment: Do you know exactly the `Type` of array?

Comment: @Sweeper [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XzA5ZgL8okHXp-X7f2tocK-mqcpfSkiH/view?usp=share_link) here

Comment: @MartinBaulig No

Comment: @justSMTHc _"@Sweeper link here "_ - that's not how SO works. Add everything that is relevant to the question _in_ the question. (Not as link and code not as image, too)

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez I can use reflection

Comment: What is wrong with `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: @Selvin I am making my own parser as a home project

Comment: in object to json you need something like this ... methods should 1. check if object is primitive or string if so - write it, 2. check if it can be enumerated as in Enigmativity answer write start of array (`[`) and iterrate and call itself with element 3. in other case write start of the object (`{`) iterate properties/fields write it name and call itself for each property value

Comment: @Selvin I already have done it, I just need to get values from the array that put into theobject, to write them

Comment: I don't see this in your code ... your `ReadObject` assumes that `obj` is object not primitive (or string), not array - just object ... there is no checking there is no `SerializeArray` call

Comment: it's pretty easy - [most cases but not escaping characters in string/char](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9DNQ1e)

Comment: well, beside `decimal` ... which can be fixed with `if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(decimal))`

Comment: @Selvin checking is in another file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was so easy:

```
 if(obj is Array arr) {
    foreach( var item in arr ) {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, what's wrong with simply casting it back to what it is?

```
int[] array = obj as int[];
```

Comment: I need to put this object into a method, so I can not do it.

Comment: Refactor the method? If the method needs to access an element of an `int[]`, it probably should _know_ it's an `int[]` to begin with.

Comment: I making jsonParser I cant? I need to make universal method

Comment: Look. We don't know what you are trying to do and why. You need to tell us. We cannot possibly give reasonable advice when 99% of information needed to come up with it are lacking.

Comment: @Fildor this not solving my problem